# Dynamically changing the attributes of particle-system component in Aframe

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to dynamically change the value of "enabled" to "true" in the particle-system component. This does not seem to work:

```
function startStarshow(){
        snowEnt.setAttribute("particle-system.enabled", "true");
      }
```

and I'm wondering if there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the property: `setAttribute(<component>, <property>, <value>)`:

```
setAttribute("particle-system", "enabled", "true");
```